# Grammar question - had died

Tags: grammar

I am writing a paper on the Roman Empire and I have a problem. Is the following sentence correct? It doesn't sound too well for me.

> When a client king had died, Romans replaced him with one of their educated hostages.

Comment: And what do you think about “*When a client king died...*”?

Comment: If using the pluperfect "had died", my inclination would be to use "where", rather than "when". "Where a client king had died...* sounds more idiomatic to me.

Comment: Why not just "when a client king died"?

Comment: "When a client king had died" leads me to think you describe one specific such situation.  "When a client king died" leads me to think that this is what typically happened when kings died, and that you are not specifically talking about one king.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between constructions such as "When a client king died..." and "When a client king *had* died" is that the former suggests something resembling simultaneity, whereas the latter makes it clear that the replacement (in the case of the example offered) was a *subsequent* event. Perhaps a simpler alternative: "After a client king died, Romans replaced him with one of their educated hostages."